# Can't run idle3

Tags: raspbian, python

I followed [this guide on learning Python](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-intro/), but can't get idle3 to open.

I've made sure I have the tools installed, by running `sudo apt-get install idle3`.

This is the error message I am getting after running `idle3 intro.py &`

```
[1] 3307
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle3", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1405, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1701, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

[1]+  Exit 1                  idle3 intro.py
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

Running just `idle3` gives the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see no DISPLAY it generally means the program (or part of it) wants to run under the X Windows GUI.

Try startx to run the graphical X environment.